# MVVM Light UserControl Not Displaying in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I'm a bit lost as to what I'm missing to get a UserControl View (`ImagePositionView`) to load and display through `MainWindow`; I've been using MVVM Light as a framework to facilitate this. At the moment all that is happening is that the namespace path of the ViewModel is displayed in MainWindow, not the expected image.

Here are the relevant files, so hopefully it is something simple that has escaped me.

ImagePositionView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PixelPosition.View.ImagePositionView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PixelPosition"
             DataContext="{Binding ImagePosition, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000" Background="White">
    <Grid>

        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="ColourImage" Source="{Binding ColourImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace PixelPosition.ViewModel
{

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string title = "This stupid thing isn't working :(";

        public string Title
        {
            get { return this.title; }
            set
            {
                if (this.title == value) return;
                this.title = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

ImagePositionViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace PixelPosition.ViewModel
{
    public class ImagePositionViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private WriteableBitmap colourBitmap = null;

        public ImageSource ColourImage
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colourBitmap;
            }
        }

        public ImagePositionViewModel()
        {
            // Open image to writeablebitmap
            string path = @"C:\Some\Path\To\ColorImage.png";

            Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];

            int width = source.PixelWidth;
            int height = source.PixelHeight;
            int stride = source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8 * width;
            byte[] data = new byte[stride * height];
            source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

            this.colourBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, source.Format, null);
            this.colourBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data, stride, 0);

        }

    }
}
```

ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace PixelPosition.ViewModel
{

    public class ViewModelLocator
    {

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ImagePositionViewModel>();
        }

        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public ImagePositionViewModel ImagePosition
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ImagePositionViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="PixelPosition.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PixelPosition"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PixelPosition.ViewModel"
             d1p1:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="PixelPosition.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PixelPosition"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="800" Width="1000">
    <Grid Margin="10 0 10 0">
        <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ImagePosition, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: the constructor in the ImagePositionViewModel is ManualSelectionViewModel ? that's a typo right ?

Comment: @SamTheDev Yep, it was a typo, trying to provide a simpler/more generic example of my problem code. That one is fixed now, so hopefully there isn't any other typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, i will try to enumerate them one by one :

**First**

In the MainWindow View, the Content of the `ContentControl` is bond to an `ImagePositionViewModel` instance which is wrong, the content needs to be bond to an instance of the `UserControl`:

```
 <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <ContentControl  >
            <YourNameSpace:ImagePositionView/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Border>
```

you may consider binding the `Content` property of the ContentControl to a property defined in the **MainViewModel** that will hold a reference to the `UserControl` that you want to show.

**Second**

In the `ImagePositionViewModel` you need to properly define the `ColourImage` property and set it with the `bitmapImage` instead of setting the field `colourBitmap`, That way the UI will be notified since the `RaisePropertyChanged` will be called :

```
public const string ColourImagePropertyName = "ColourImage";
    private WriteableBitmap  colourBitmap =  null;
    public WriteableBitmap  ColourImage
    {
        get
        {
            return colourBitmap ;
        }

        set
        {
            if (Equals(colourBitmap, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            colourBitmap  = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ColourImagePropertyName);
        }
    }
```

and set the property instead of the fild:

```
 //...
 int stride = source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8 * width;
 byte[] data = new byte[stride * height];
 source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
 var cb = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, source.Format, null);
 cb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data, stride, 0);
 ColourImage=cb;
```

**Finally**

your code should work by now, but still, it is a bad idea to load the image in the constructor of the VM, you should define a `Loaded` Command in your UserControl's ViewModel and bind the `Loaded` event to that command using `EventToCommand`, so in the `ImagePosition` Vm define a `LoadedCommand` like this :

```
 private RelayCommand _loadedCommand;
    public RelayCommand LoadedCommand 
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadedCommand
                ?? (_loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    // Open image to writeablebitmap
                    string path = @"C:\Some\Path\To\ColorImage.png";

                    Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                    var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                    BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];

                    int width = source.PixelWidth;
                    int height = source.PixelHeight;
                    int stride = source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8 * width;
                    byte[] data = new byte[stride * height];
                    source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

                    var cb = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, source.Format, null);
                    cb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data, stride, 0);
                    ColourImage = cb;
                }));
        }
    }
```

*and remove the image loading code from the Vm contructor,

then in the `ImagePositionView` `usercontrol` bind the `loaded` event to the command you've defined :

```
    //..
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000" Background="White" >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}"
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
 //..
```

you should add the following namespaces :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

Comment: The `mvvmLight6`, is that a reference to a particular assembly that should be at the top of MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Nah, that my namespace, use yours instead

Comment: Cool, that got it going, now to go through the rest of your suggestions.

Comment: This is probably outside the scope of a comment, but when binding the Content property of the ContentControl to a property defined in the MainViewModel for holding a reference to the UserControl that I want to show. Is this outside what the ViewModelLocator is for, or do I use it in a particular fashion for this?

Comment: the ViewModelLocator is simply a bridge between the view and the ViewModel, don't use it for something else, besides that keep in mind that the Vm instance won't  be created  until its View is rendered

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `MainWindow`'s `Resources` collection in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImagePositionViewModel}">
        <local:ImagePositionView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Note, your namespace may differ, mine is `local`.

`ImagePositionViewModel` was correctly loaded into the `ContentControl`, the problem was that it just didn't know how to actually "render" it, so we provided a `DataTemplate` for it.

Comment: Does the Window.Resources change if the view/viewmodel changes? As in if I have two views and I switch between them?